# c++ permutations of input

Tags: c++, vector, permutation

So I'm trying to take a user input of a couple of different numbers and have an output of every possible permutation of these numbers, in c++. Currently it works for up to three different numbers. I however can't figure out what stops it from taking on more numbers and was hoping to get some answers here.

Furthermore, whenever it does work; it segmentation faults even when the input is only a single number.

Here is the code, any ideas?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    ////////////////creating the list which'll be permutated
    string korp = "64832965k";
    cout << "input your numbers, signal that you're done with 'n' \n";
    vector<int> dude;
    int fit = 0;
    while (korp[0] != 'n') {

        cin >> korp;
        if (korp[0] != 'n') {

            int thisis = 0;
            int hit = 0;
            while (korp[hit] != '\0') {

                thisis = thisis * 10 + (korp[hit] - 48);
                hit++;
            }

            dude.push_back(thisis);
            fit++;
        }
    }
    vector<bool> in(fit, false);
    vector<int> intin(fit, 0);
    vector<vector<bool> > minds;
    minds.push_back(in);
    vector<vector<int> > mines;
    mines.push_back(intin);

    /////////permutation of the list

    int things = 0;
    int seed = 0;

    //permutation tree loop start

    for (int curr = 0; curr < dude.size(); curr++) {

        int tanks = things;

        while (things == tanks) { //runs until the next element of the original list should be added
            int position = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < fit; i++) {
                if (dude[curr] == mines[seed][i] && minds[seed][i] == true) {
                    position = i;
                }
            }

            while (position < fit) {

                if (minds[seed][position] == false) {
                    minds.push_back(minds[seed]);
                    minds.back()[position] = true;
                    mines.push_back(mines[seed]);
                    mines.back()[position] = dude[curr];
                }
                position++;
            }

            seed++;
            things = 0;

            for (int q = 0; q < fit; q++) {
                if (minds[seed][q] == true) {
                    things++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //permutation tree loop end

    ////////outputs the permutations
    minds.push_back(in);
    mines.push_back(intin);

    int whom = 0;
    int bom = sizeof(minds);
    while (whom < bom) {

        bool oped = true;

        for (int z = 0; z < fit; z++) { //checks if the current vector is a permutation
            if (minds[whom][z] == false) {
                oped = false;
            }
        }
        if (oped == true) {
            cout << '(';
            for (int a = 0; a < fit; a++) {
                cout << mines[whom][a] << ',';
            }
            cout << ')' << '\n';
        }
        whom++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The quickest way to solve your problem would be to use [std::next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation)

Comment: The best way to complicate the debugging is to ignore indentation completely.

Comment: frankly there are too many problems in your code, for example `int bom=sizeof(minds);`. `sizeof` does not return the number of elements in a vector, rather it is the size of the vector object (which is constant). I have the impression that you wrote too much code at once without thorough testing. Without explanation or comments, the logic of your code is not obvious

Comment: @idclev463035818 should the size of the vector increase as the default allocated memory space is used up? Of course it's still is no clear indication for the length of the vector.

Comment: @silentin What is "the default allocated memory space"? Anyway, no, since the number of elements is not a compile-time constant, `vector`s cannot have different `sizeof`s from that.

Comment: @silentin the size of an object (or all objects of one type) is always constant. Of course `struct foo { int * x; };` can point to arrays of different size, but `sizeof(foo)` is a constant.

Comment: If it segfaults, then it doesn't work, even if it accidentally seemed to print some correct value before dying. You need to fix the code. The simplest way to do that yourself is to learn how to use a debugger. Or just use the Standard library facilities that already exist until you're confident enough to reinvent them. You should take some time to progressively reduce this program in an attempt to isolate the problem before posting it on SO, or at least try to explain what it's doing with all those baffling variable names, rather than requiring others to guess.

Comment: @Bob__ since c++11 `str[str.size()]` returns a reference to a null character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to throw your code away and start over. You overcomplicated it and it's more difficult to fix it.

Divide your main function into two parts:

- Read input
- Print permutations

```
int main() {
    const auto input = readInput();
    printPermutations(input);
}
```

You divide your problem into two smaller problems and you already solved the first problem.

```
auto readInput() {
    std::string korp;
    std::cout << "input your numbers, signal that you're done with 'n' \n";
    std::vector<int> dude;
    do {
        std::cin >> korp;
        if (korp[0] != 'n') {
            int thisis = 0;
            for (const auto c : korp) {
                thisis = thisis * 10 + (c - 48);
            }
            dude.push_back(thisis);
        }
    } while (korp[0] != 'n');
    return dude;
}
```

For the second problem you should use STL. Don't reinvent the wheel.

First sort the container with [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). Then iterate in a loop over the permutations you get with [`std::next_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation).

```
void printPermutations(std::vector<int> input) {
    std::sort(std::begin(input), std::end(input));
    do {
        for (const auto num : input) {
            std::cout << num << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    } while (std::next_permutation(std::begin(input), std::end(input)));
}
```

The necessary headers are

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
```

Input:

```
1 12 4 123 n
```

Output:

```
1 4 12 123 
1 4 123 12 
1 12 4 123 
1 12 123 4 
1 123 4 12 
1 123 12 4 
4 1 12 123 
4 1 123 12 
4 12 1 123 
4 12 123 1 
4 123 1 12 
4 123 12 1 
12 1 4 123 
12 1 123 4 
12 4 1 123 
12 4 123 1 
12 123 1 4 
12 123 4 1 
123 1 4 12 
123 1 12 4 
123 4 1 12 
123 4 12 1 
123 12 1 4 
123 12 4 1
```